# Spring Data neo4j translates neo4j's NotFoundException to an InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException instead of an DataRetrievalFailureException

Tags: exception, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We're using neo4j 1.8.2 Advanced with Spring Data neo4j 2.2.0.RELEASE and Spring Framework 3.2.0.RELEASE. We're using a lot of custom queries. The queries are defined using the @Query annotation in our repository interfaces.

While writing tests we encountered a problem with one of our queries. As far as we know, when a query uses a start node which does not exists neo4j throws a `NotFoundException` which will be then translated to a `DataRetrievalFailureException`.

But for our query the exception is translated to an `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` instead which normally indicates that the query is not correct. We think that our query looks good so we don't understand why the `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` gets thrown. When we test it with an existing start node the query returns the expected results.

The query:

```
START person = node({0})
MATCH person -[attributeRel:ATTRIBUTE]-> attribute -[:ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY]-> category 
WHERE attributeRel.value! <> 'N' AND attributeRel.value! <> 'Unbekannt/nicht bewertet' 
RETURN category, COLLECT(attribute), COLLECT(attributeRel) 
ORDER BY category.name"
```

Is this a bug in Spring Data neo4j or is our query wrong or is the exception type correct and we just don't understand why it get's thrown.

Comment: Is there any way you can try out the query to neo4j to find out where the error is? like `neo4jTemplate.query`  and see what happens

Comment: I also posted the question in the neo4j Google Group, it seems to be a bug. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/i5Bc-N0mFOU

Comment: Not a bug, rather a shortcoming. Did you raise a JIRA issue?

Comment: JIRA issue was added right now.